# Doxygen strip closing instructions of comments in code block in markdown

Tags: comments, markdown, doxygen

When i try to include code block in .md(markdown) file, doxygen strip closing instruction of comments. How can i insert multiline comment with /** ... */ instructions in markdown file? STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS parametr set to NO

```
Example:
~~~~
namespace ExternalApi\Model;
/**
* Description of class
*/
class Exception extends AbstractException
{}
~~~~
```

Doxygen output:

```
namespace ExternalApi\Model;
/**
* Description of class

class Exception extends AbstractException
{}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (current version is 1.8.12)?  What is the extension of your file where this comment is in? What happens if you just place the menioned snippet in an markdown file?

Comment: I use 1.8.6 (I know, that this is not actual version, but we need this version, because of capability with our old markdown files with many h1), extension of our files .md (markdown file). My code block already placed in markdown file. Is this a known bug in my old version, or may be exists secret option to decide this problem?

Comment: Looks to me like a bug in the old version. In the 1.8.12 version it is OK. What is the problem you encounter with the newer version(s)? Maybe you can refer to an existing bug report for this or otherwise create one or file an extension request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was a bug. 
In 1.8.7 all works. 
In 1.8.12 it works too